# package.json is overwritten by another in multi-stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a vuejs app and a nodejs express server inside a single container. But i'm struggling with building the frontend. After renaming the instruction to build the server from "npm run build" to "npm run buildserver", The logs say "npm ERR! Missing script: build" suggesting that the frontend package.json was replaced by the backend one.

The structure is as follows :

```
root
|- docker-compose.yml
|- Dockerfile
|- backend
||- server.js
||- package.json
|- frontend
||- package.json
||- src
|||- main.js
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:20 as frontend

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./backend/package*.json ./
RUN npm install --omit=dev
RUN npm install vite @vitejs/plugin-vue
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:20
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./front/package*.json ./
RUN npm install --omit=dev
RUN npm install webpack webpack-cli
COPY . .
RUN npm run buildserver
COPY --from=frontend /front/dist ./public

CMD npm start
```

The server runs fine if I only use "npm run build" but that hides the real issue. I would appreciate a lot if someone could figure out the corrections needed to this Dockerfile in order for the backend to access the dist folder containing the frontend :)

Comment: In both build stages, you start by copying `package.json` from either a `front` or `backend` directory, but then you copy the entire parent directory (including its `package.json`, if there is one) over the current directory.  Do you need to change the two `COPY . .` lines?

Comment: I read it was good practice to copy the package.json to the Dockerfile directory, many examples I saw online did it. But i'm very confused about this, so if you have any alternative solution that works I would gladly use it

Comment: One thing you might try is commenting out everything from the troublesome `RUN npm run build` command to the end of the file; `docker build` an image out of that, and `docker run --rm -it that-image bash` to get a debugging shell in a temporary container.  What do you see when you look around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it thanks to github repository https://github.com/dirmeier/docker-nginx-vue-express-node-sqlite-app-template/blob/master/Dockerfile

The solution was to install and build the server and frontend in their own folders. It seems kind of obvious but I struggled a lot to find the correct way to write this Dockerfile.

Here it is :

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /app/frontend

WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY frontend/ ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

WORKDIR /app
COPY backend/ ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run buildserver

EXPOSE 3080
CMD npm run start
```